Laravel Passport authorize
I am attempting to establish a Single Sign-On (SSO) with Laravel and Laravel/Passport, but I am facing a problem. The /oauth/authorize route returns JSON for an invalid client and a view (the authorize page) for a valid client. Could I be making a mistake? Shouldn't it be standard to return both views or JSON for these scenarios?
I set up a new Laravel application, installed Laravel/Passport, created a client using the command php artisan passport:client, and accessed the page http://localhost:8000/oauth/authorize?client_id=<client_id>&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fauth%2Fcallback&response_type=code&scope=. For a valid client ID, I receive the authorize page, but for an invalid client ID, I receive JSON. I anticipate receiving HTML pages in both cases, or if the header accepts application/json, I expect to receive JSON for both valid and invalid clients.

use Laravel\Passport\Exceptions\OAuthServerException;

public function render($request, Throwable $exception){
if ($exception instanceof OAuthServerException) 
{
  return response()->view('errors.oauth', [], 500);
}
  return parent::render($request, $exception);
}


Although this code might answer the question, I recommend that you also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.
